# Get last 2 parts of lines

Tags: bash, shell, sh

i' ve a stream of paths, and i' d like to get the last 2 parts of them.

Input:

```
/a/b/c/d/e
/path/to/some/thing
/foo/bar
```

Output:

```
d/e
some/thing
foo/bar
```

. How can i do it the simpliest way with bash (through a pipeline).

Thanks.

Comment: Try using sed to dump out the latter part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {print $(NF-1), $NF}' file

d/e
some/thing
foo/bar
```

Using `sed`:

```
sed -E 's~.*/([^/]*/[^/]*)$~\1~' file

d/e
some/thing
foo/bar
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
rev f|cut -d / -f 1,2|rev
```

Comment: Well, I took the OP's request literally: Implement it in bash, using a pipeline  ;-)  Actually, I wouldn't consider it tricky - the basic idea behind this code is a pattern we often use in programming -, but  it is a bit inefficient, due to the 3 child processes involved. If efficiency is important, the *sed* solution proposed by anubhava is perhaps best.